Velo change videobox video file after one play and continue to loop the second video
I’m trying to achieve this functionality on my page using Velo:
There is a button and a videobox on the page. The videobox is hidden by default, and the video file loaded in the Editor is video1. The videobox Behaviour settings are set to: “starts to play On Click”, “No Pause”, “Stops when it ends”.
When the button is hovered over, the videobox shows and starts to play. When video1 has played to the end, the videobox loads and plays video2, and video2 continues to play on a loop.
$w.onReady(function () {
  const video1 = "wix:video";
  const video2 = "wix:video";

//I have redacted the paths of the videos for this post

  const videobox = $w("#videoBox1");
  const button = $w("#Button1");
  let firstPlay = true;

  button.onMouseIn(() => {
    videoBox.show();
    videoBox.play();
  });

  button.onMouseOut(() => {
    videoBox.hide();
    videoBox.stop();
  });

  videoBox.onEnded(() => {
    if (firstPlay) {
      videoBox.src = video2;
      firstPlay = false;
    }
    videoBox.play();
  });
});


When previewing, everything is normal until video2 gets loaded, and it seems that it gets loaded but never plays. What am I doing wrong?

Update:
I tested this again and discovered that while the video will not play, its “isPlaying” property is “true” for some reason. What is going on here?

It might be due to loading dela, if you can do it use async/await if not create a small timeout for play part. Basically add this:
$w('#videoBox1').onEnded(() => {
    if (firstPlay) {
      videoBox.src = video2;
      firstPlay = false;
    }

    setTimeour(() => {
      videoBox.play();
    }, 100);
})

Try this one first and play with the 100ms delay change it to 200, 500 or something else and see if it's working if does it means there is some delay to load the video when you change the src so you should work with async/await if possible if not add timeout like I did above.

Hi, thank you for the answer. However I can’t seem to get it to work using settimeout. Could you alternatively elaborate on the sync await approach?

@HullBreaker maybe try to use togglePlay() function in the end where you start playing video2 or add stop() function before playing it. I'm not sure if it'll work but you can try it if timeout didn't work.
We can't async/await .src changes so it won't be possible when I recheck your code at least this is what I think.
